# How to programmatically update data in WFS geoserver layer

Tags: python, geoserver

I am building an application where the user retrieves all the features of a geoserver layer (store: postgres) and display them on a table. For doing this I use the OWSLib (get_feature).

Now I need to add the functionality of editing the data (WFS-T). As far as I know OWSLib doesn't provide an add/update feature functionality.

What would be the way to implement this kind of functionality?

As suggested I use python requests lib in order to implement the WFS-T and updated values on the layer:

This is part of my code:

```
      import requests
      url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs'


      xml = """<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
      xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Update typeName="geonode:tjk_nhr_shockriskscore">
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:Name>Adm2_NAME</wfs:Name>
      <wfs:Value>test_2dsfdsfsdfdsfds</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:FeatureId fid="tjk_nhr_shockriskscore.1"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>"""
      headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'} # set what your server accepts
      print requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers).text
```

When I run this xml through the geoserver Demo pages, it works fine. The property of the layer gets update.
When I execute it through my python script I get a service exception as:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <ServiceExceptionReport
     version="1.2.0"
     xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
  <ServiceException>
   {http://www.geonode.org/}tjk_nhr_shockriskscore is read-only
  </ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184309/available-python-client-libraries-for-wfs-transactions

Comment: Ah great. Haven't found that link. It helps although it seems they way is not paved smoothly, right?

Comment: These are just HTTP post requests with a well defined standard

Comment: Yes ofcource. But what I meant is that I need to make a function which will build the request message including all the properties to be updated. Itsn't difficult but I am surprised that none of the existing libs provide something!

Comment: You can use owslib to get all the properties then construct the HTTP request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message (unusually) is actually helpful here - if the layer is read only you can't run an update against it. So the question then becomes why is the layer read only? The most likely reason (especially if the transaction works in the demo page) is that your python script didn't authenticate with the server. From [this page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) it looks like you need to add:

```
auth=("admin","geoserver")
```

to your request (assuming you haven't changed the default password).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it. It would take lots of time to find out this!